# Error installing qtService help into assistant

Tags: qt, qt4

I got the Qt Solutions from http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions, and have a trouble trying to install its docs into assistant - I can see documentation menu, but page text is not displaying.

What I have done:

```
D:\WORK\Repos\qt-solutions\qtservice\doc\html>qhelpgenerator qtservice.qhp -o qtservice.qch
Building up file structure...
Insert custom filters...
Insert help data for filter section (1 of 1)...
Insert files...
Insert contents...
Insert indices...
Documentation successfully generated.

D:\WORK\Repos\qt-solutions\qtservice\doc\html>assistant -register qtservice.qch
```

Assistant says that documentation succesfully imported, but shows only menu headers (no html help texts). 
qtservice.qch has a size of 53 kb, so I think html was succesfully embedded in it.

My QT version is 4.6.3, running on WinXP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with Qt 4.7.1 (running on Vista), but does not work with 4.6.2 on the same machine. I assume the help files use features that were not supported in Qt 4.6.